# Forward-declare a member enumeration of a class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, enums, forward-declaration

With C++11's strongly typed `enum`s, it is possible to declare a member enumeration of a class like so:

```cpp
class X {
public:
    enum class E;
};

enum class X::E { a, b };
```

However, when making `X` a class template:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class X {
public:
    enum class E;
};

template <typename T>
enum class X<T>::E { a, b };
```

gcc 4.7.2 and clang 3.0 both complain with "error: ‘enum X::E’ is an enumeration template [-pedantic]" and "error: enumeration cannot be a template", respectively. The section of the standard I think is relevant (and which, in fact, this question originated from) is §14 Templates, the first paragraph of which states:

> The *declaration* in a *template-declaration* shall
>
> - declare or define a function or a class, or
> - **define** a member function, a member class, **a member enumeration**, or a static data member **of a class template** or of a class nested within a class template, or
> - define a member template of a class or class template, or
> - be an *alias-declaration*.

(emphasis mine). So is this a compiler bug, or am I mis-interpreting the statement entirely?

Comment: gcc 4.8.1 still considers [it is an error](http://rextester.com/BATQ56315), whereas clang 3.4 [does not](http://rextester.com/UIZ27560).

Comment: Compiles with gcc 4.8.2.

Comment: @evnu Even with `-pedantic-errors` compiler flag?

Comment: @Constructor my bad, I forgot the parameter. No, it throws a warning as well.

Comment: @Constructor: Yes, this looks promising. Want to post it as an answer?

Comment: @Taral I think it is not an answer, it is only a comment. I don't know what compiler is right in this situation.

Comment: @Constructor of course it's no proof, but it works for me as enough of an indication. Still, if someone more standard-savvy can answer it, all the better ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been asked for creating this answer. See paragraph [temp.mem.enum] 14.5.1.4/1 of the C++ standard:

> An enumeration member of a class template may be defined outside the
>   class template definition. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T> struct A {
>   enum E : T;
> };
> A<int> a;
> template<class T> enum A<T>::E : T { e1, e2 };
> A<int>::E e = A<int>::e1;
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

Newer version of *clang* (3.4) [compiles your code successfully](http://rextester.com/UIZ27560) with flag `-pedantic-errors` whereas *gcc* 4.8.1 [still considers it is an error](http://rextester.com/BATQ56315). I think it is a *gcc* bug.

Comment: Well, that settles it. Probably should've read a bit further ... thanks for the effort!